# Change checkbox status based on textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, checkbox, textbox

I have a form in my site & there is a **Read-Only** textbox in my form. This textbox will dynamically get its value (A, B, C or D) from URL.
then i have some checkboxes below this textbox.
what i want is to change the status of these checkboxes based on the value of that textbox.

for example if the textbox1 value was **A**, then checkbox1, checkbox3 & checkbox6 become checked.
I tried somthing like this but it didn't work:

```
$("#textbox1").change(function(){
    var txt1=$("#textbox1").val();
        if(txt1=='A'){
        $(":checkbox[name='checkbox1']").prop('checked',true);
            $(":checkbox[name='checkbox3']").prop('checked',true);
        $(":checkbox[name='checkbox6']").prop('checked',true);
        }
        else {
        //nothing
      }
      });
```

thanks.

Comment: How are you detecting that the textbox value has changed? what event have you hooked up?

Comment: What scartag said, you need to show us how you change the value in #textbox1 to begin with!

Comment: dear scartag, i am using `$("#textbox1").change(function(){`. (is it correct for a textbox?) actually i am using contact form 7 with dynamic text extension in wordpress.

Comment: That won't work if you are programatically changing the value, and since it's read-only you probably are. You need to set the checkboxes at the same time you set the textfields value programatically.

Comment: I'll even add a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm6za/) to demonstrate, as changing the value of a textbox with javascipt does not trigger the change event, and the only way you can change the value on a read-only textbox is with javascript. You'll need to trigger the change event or do it differently.

Comment: dear adeneo, i am geting textbox value from the URL using GET method. for example http://domain.com/form?textbox1=A
this will set textbox1 value to A on page load.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the change event for the textbox and then evaluate which checkbox to check.
Like so:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myTextbox").on("change",function(){
        var $Textbox = $(this);
        var NewCheckbox;
        switch ($Textbox.val()){
            case "A":
                NewCheckbox = $("#checkboxA");
                break;
            case "B":
                NewCheckbox = $("#checkboxB");
                break;
            case "C":
                NewCheckbox = $("#checkboxC");
                break;
        }
        $("#checkboxA").attr('checked',false);
        $("#checkboxB").attr('checked',false);
        $("#checkboxC").attr('checked',false);

        NewCheckbox.attr('checked',true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Probably not, thats just habit